# make notification clickable and undestroyable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I tried to create a notification that starts a activity by clicking on it and which you can't swipe away.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("DroidSchool")
                .setContentText("DroidSchool l\u00E4uft im Hintergrund...");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        
        int mId = 1234567890;
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

with the code above the notification gets displayed, but nothing happens when I click on it and you can swipe it away.

Comment: The issue is mostly with the intent...

Comment: if it is undestroyable, how will you ever be able to remove it then?

Comment: @bofredo when the app is closed. i mean for example like the avast notification

Comment: Have not tried it, but maybe [a foreground service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) is what you're looking for?

Comment: if you use a service with a notification you should use ForegroundService !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the Notification, in that way the user can't click it away in any way, add this flag

```
Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, notification);
```

To start an Activity you have to use this flag for your Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: @NathanMaier Is this code running in a Service? Which Activity you wanna start by clicking, the previous one as you left the App?

Comment: yes its in a service but it works now (i added `noti.contentIntent = pendingIntent;`)

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("DroidSchool")
            .setContentText("DroidSchool l\u00E4uft im Hintergrund...");

    Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);


   Notification noti = mBuilder.build();

   noti.flags |= mBuilder.build().FLAG_NO_CLEAR | mBuilder.build().FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
    manager.notify(0, noti);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a foreground service as detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)

It's worth noting that only android 4.3 added the persistent notification you seem to be after and it can be overriden by the users settings.

Answer (score 0):

try using like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

in MainActivity.java

Dont not consume your notification; ie instead of calling below 2 line code in oncreate() call under onDestro()

```
 NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.cancel(mId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NotificationCompat.Builder`'s `.setOngoing(true)`, use it like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder  builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                                     .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                     .setContentTitle("Downloading Something")
                                                     .setContentText("Downloading")
                                                     .setSound(null)
                                                     .setDefaults(0)
                                                     .setOngoing(true);
// Makes it so the notification is clickable but not destroyable by swiping-away or hitting "clear all"
```